# how to add a library to 'make' command in c

Tags: c, makefile, cs50

This is the header file and its C file: 
[`cs50.h`](http://mirror.cs50.net/library50/c/cs50-library-c-3.0/cs50.h) and 
[`cs50.c`](http://mirror.cs50.net/library50/c/cs50-library-c-3.0/cs50.c)

Now I use them in the <s>following</s> example http://www.paste.ubuntu.com/576370/ — which is no longer available.

I already put the header file in `/usr/bin/include` or something like that and when I try to compile my code using `gcc -o xxx xxx.c`, it doesn't work, so tried to fix this and the following way worked: http://www.paste.ubuntu.com/576371/ — which is no longer available.

Now I want to do something to make the 'make' command work as the `gcc` does.

What do I need to do?

---

The following was the old topic:

> I was using `gcc` command to
>   compile C programs but after a period
>   of time I got a problem. I need
>   to compile a new header file and use
>   it as a library.
>
> The header file called `cs50.h`.
>
> so after doing it and it's ok I can
>   compile using the following
>
> ```
> gcc -o xxx xxx.c -lcs50
> ```
>
> It works but now I want to use 'make'
>   command and I can't get it to work.
>
> It just don't compile the header file
>   and library as gcc was before I edit
>   it to accept the cs50 library.
>
> So now I want to add to the 'make'
>   command the following: `-lcs50`
>
> Can anyone help me in this please?

Comment: Someone can probably help *if you show us your Makefile*.

Comment: The Ubuntu pastes have been deleted. This question is not useful to others without them.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the links defining the code and problems are no longer available, and the information here is not compellingly unique (there are many other questions about similar problems).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Near the top of your Makefile, add the line:

```
LDLIBS = -lcs50
```

If you are using Make's default (implicit) rules for the building, then that is all you need to do.  If you are using explicit rules, you will need to add $(LDLIBS) to your explicit rules.

If there is no Makefile, then make is using default rules, and you can either just create a makefile with

```
echo LDLIBS = -lcs50 > Makefile
```

or tell make to link with certain libraries by specifying the required libraries in LDLIBS in the environment.  For example, if you are using a sh-derived shell (anything other than csh or tcsh) you can do:

```
LDLIBS=-lcs50 make target
```

If you are using a csh variant, you can do:

```
env LDLIBS=-lcs50 make target
```

or just do (again, for non-csh shells)

```
export LDLIBS=-lcs50
```

before running make. (For csh variants, do setenv LDLIBS -lcs50)

Comment: @Xmasterrrr $EDITOR Makefile  (ie, "vi Makefile", or "emacs makefile" or "nedit GNUMakefile" .... the possibilities are endless)

Comment: where is the location of it ?

Comment: sorry but i think i got it wrongly... so i don't know if you mean that's the make file is a thing that produced when i compile the source code or what ?

Comment: @Xmasterrrr The makefile is usually located in the same directory from which you run make.  It will be called either 'makefile' or 'Makefile' or 'GNUmakefile'.  It may be elsewhere (eg, it might be RCS/Makefile,v), but probably not.

Comment: @Xmasterrrr Instead of running 'make', what happens if you run 'cat makefile' (try the various names, or do 'ls ?ake*' to get a listing)  What platform are you on?

Comment: when i write make hai3 for example it give me the following
cc     hai3.c   -o hai3

/tmp/ccEVl7B9.o: In function `main':

hai3.c:(.text+0x1b): undefined reference to `GetString'

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [hai3] Error 1

Comment: @Xmasterrrr The makefile is not something that is produced when you compile.  When you run 'make', the first thing it does is try to find a makefile, and it uses that to know what commands it is supposed to run: http://www.gnu.org/software/make/

Comment: so it's not there , iam using ubuntu and i can't find the make file :S

Comment: does it all use the first makefile that has been made ? if yes i can't remember where can i find it... if so can i just remake a new makefile ?

Comment: @Xmasterrr Good.  If you have no makefile, then make is just using default rules, so things will be easy.  Just do "export LDLIBS=-lcs50".  You will need to do this in all shells from which you want to run make.

Comment: Thanks @WilliamPursell I just used this on my mac using `export LDLIBS=-lcs50` in my zshrc file. Cheers!

Comment: I've resisted the temptation to edit in `make LDLIBS=-cs50 program` as a way of compiling the program that avoids all the shell-specific variants, but surely that would be easiest — at least one-off.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below “make” command to link library and include header directories,

```
make <.c or .cpp source filename_without_extension> LDLIBS="-l<lib1> -l<lib2>"
```

suppose you have server.cpp file to compile using make command,

```
make server LDLIBS="-lcpprest -lpthread -lssl -lcrypto" LDFLAGS="-L/usr/lib/" CXXFLAGS="-I/usr/include/"
```

Output will expand the compilation command as,

```
g++ -I/usr/include/  -L/usr/lib/  server.cpp  -lcpprest -lpthread -lssl -lcrypto -o server
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you forget that you have to tell gcc in what directory the CS50 library is located?

```
gcc … -L/directory/for/cs50_library -lcs50
```